# javascript: prototype issue with fat arrow function

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am facing some issue or may it something new comes with fat-arrow function while implementing prototype.

Here is the problem::

```
function baseClass() {
   this.name = "Pankaj";
}

baseClass.prototype.fnGetName = function() {
   return this.name;
};

baseClass.prototype.fatArrayGetName = () => {
  return this.name;
};

var classObject = new baseClass();
```

Now when I try to retrieve name property of class using methods as:

```
classObject.name; // returns Pankaj
classObject.fnGetName() // returns Pankaj
classObject.fatArrayGetName() // returns ""    (EMPTY STRING)
```

Just want to know why **fatArrayGetName** function return empty string where as it should return name property value.

Comment: That because the Arrow function is binding automatically with the declaration context.

Comment: is there any way to make it work with prototype context. because i tried with call method as *classObject.fatArrayGetName.call(classObject)* but still it returns empty string